# Couchbase bucket connections

Tags: performance, asynchronous, concurrency, couchbase, nosql

I have a Couchbase cluster with two nodes and a tcp server inserting unique keys into it.

The tcp server can handle multiple async connections and for each message it receives it will insert a key.

The Couchbase documentation says that one should reuse cluster and bucket connection, but I noticed that when sharing one bucket connection I start seeing "The operation has timed out" errors when going above 60 connections. But if I use one bucket connection for each server connection this doesn't happen.

I am using the Go SDK.

Comment: Can you indicate which SDK you're using and the versions?  The term 'TCP server' is a bit too generic to discern what you have running here.

Comment: @MattIngenthron I'm using the Go SDK. It's really just a simple tcp server accepting 200 bytes messages, inserting them into Couchbase and then returning some confirmation message.